# Ejecutar una sola vez una función al cargar la página - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente código que representa un mensaje de bienvenida en el sitio web, ahora... he intentado que aparezca una vez se cargue la página con el `window.onload`, sin embargo también me refleja el mensaje cada que se recarga la pagina.

```
                    const mensajeBienvenida = function() {
                        const Toast = Swal.mixin({
                            toast: true,
                            position: 'bottom-end',
                            showConfirmButton: false,
                            color: "#fff", 
                            background: "#302c34",
                            timer: 2000,
                            timerProgressBar: true,
                            didOpen: (toast) => {
                                toast.addEventListener('mouseenter', Swal.stopTimer)
                                toast.addEventListener('mouseleave', Swal.resumeTimer)
                            }
                        })

                        Toast.fire({
                            icon: 'success',
                            title: '¡Bienvenido al sistema!'
                        })
                    }

window.onload = mensajeBienvenida();
```

No sé si alguien sabe una manera en la que solo detecta la función una sola vez y deje de ejecutarse.

Comment: Si recargas la pagina pues obviamente se vuelve a cargar y se ejecuta el onload... que es lo que quieres entonces?

Comment: @Pipe que la función solo se ejecute una vez, pero para que funcione el mensaje de alerta y se muestre tiene que esperar a que la página cargue y ahí es donde coloco el `window.onload` de otra forma no lo estaría usando...

Comment: Si, es correcto, el windows onload espera que la pagina cargue y ahi se muestra el mensaje. ese mensaje no se vuelve a mostrar ni a ejecutar a menos que recargues la página. Que es exactamente lo que buscas? donde está el error?

Comment: No existe error como tal, solo quiero que la función `mensajeBienvenida()` se ejecute una vez independientemente si la página se vuelve a cargar o no.

Comment: Pues se me ocurre que guardes una variable en `sessionStorage` y ejecutes el mensaje de bienvenida sólo si no existe la variable mensajeBienvenida. Algo como `if( !sessionStorage.mensajeBienvenida) {mensajeBienvenida(); sessionStorage.setItem(mensajeBienvenida, "true")};`

Comment: O quizas mejor en el `localStorage`

Comment: Gracias @ Pipe @Jaime Menéndez, ambas respuestas me sirvieron, funciona genial.

Comment: @Pipe el problema es que si lo guarda en el localStorage el usuario más nunca verá el mensaje de bienvenida. Puede pasar un, día, una semana, y no lo verá más. A menos que lo borre manualmente, se guarda indefinidamente.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez Tengo entendido que es exactamente lo que él quiere, dice que se vea una sola vez y que no se vuelva a ver asi recargue. Ya depende de lo que él quiera. Saludos